# Jenkins Dynamic Agents - Clone from VM conflicts with node/agents/labels

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to provision multiple vms from an agent template/snapshot and access them within a Jenkins job? Or does this limit have to be known ahead of time and each pre-provisioned and connected to Jenkins?

Reading the documentation on [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) and [vsphere plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/vsphere-cloud) I have this perception that I could have a template VM from which I dynamically provision as many clones as I need (limited by concurrent build limits) and connect and build on those - however when it comes to implementation I have two problems:

1) The agent tries to connect to the same nodes defined in /computer (cloning and have static ips so have lots of conflicts there)

2) If I name the vm clone as something else, the label is not recognized as a valid node (i.e. Clone from a VM attached as node 'Agent1' to 'Agent2' -- using the label 'Agent2' does not connect to the new vm since Agent2 is not a valid node)

Comment: Please elaborate on problem #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Jenkins create new nodes from a template and name them with an incrementing counter (i.e. prefix of 'WinAgent-' create 'WinAgent-1', W'WinAgent-2', etc and they show up as new nodes under the executors)

1) This is an issue of static IPs.  Use VM configurations to change the IP or setup dhcp.  Use the vm options to have Jenkins send in the name of the agent.  For example, in esx use [vmtoolsd --cmd "info-get guestinfo.SLAVE_JNLP_URL"](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/vSphere+Cloud+Plugin)  Use a script to start the agent using the parameters from the vm options.

2) When setup in the vsphere cloud portion of 'Manage Jenkins > Configure System' the system will create a new node automatically.  All you have to do in the script is use the configured label.